# create event on facebook via graph api or javascript sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want a "create event facebook popup" with preconfigured parameters.

I have bit of coding as below but i am really confused how we can go further.

My Code below

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '<appid>',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.2'
        });   
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="callEvent()"> <span>     Create Event    </span></a>

<script>
    function callEvent() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                console.log('Logged in.');
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                alert(accessToken);
                FB.api('/me/events?access_token=' + accessToken, 'post',
                    {
                        name:       "Test    event",
                        start_time: Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0)
                    },
                    function(retVal) {}
                );
            }
            else {
                console.log('initiate FB login...');
                FB.login();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Can someone help with code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I formatted your code, so it's more readable. Next time, please try to make your code more presentable, because that way you make it much easier for other people to understand your problem and help you.

Comment: Also could you be more specific about what is it you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot create events via the Graph API.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event#publish

Specifically, about user events:

> Creating
>
> You can't perform this operation on this endpoint.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events